# Iterate Paragraphs in Word

Tags: c++, ms-word, word-automation

I need to find out all the paragraphs in a word document.
Word Document gives Paragraphs using `struct Paragraphs * Paragraphs;`

The Paragraphs gives First and Last Paragraph

```
struct Paragraph * First;
struct Paragraph * Last;
```

Now I do not know how to iterate all the paragraphs.

Need Help.
    Probably has got to do something with `__declspec(property(get=Get_NewEnum))`

Comment: Has the Answer below answered your question? If yes, it would help maintain the site quality if you would mark it as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the answer's left :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Paragraph* First;
struct Paragraph* Last;
struct Paragraph* Current;

for (Current = First; Current < Last; ++Current) {
    // DO something with current
}
```

Additional info:

- Do not use raw pointers
- Do not use C-Style arrays
- Do not use pointer arithmentic
- Learn at least a minimum C++
- Read some good books
- After all that, start writing code. Not before.